# htaccess remove portion of url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

my site has urls similar to http://sitename.com/sydney/manly-beach-102.htm

i have changed my permalinks and i dont have the number in the url anymore. I would like do a 301 redirect in my htaccess file to remove the number from all the urls, they should redirect to http://sitename.com/sydney/manly-beach.htm

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With this code in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.+)-\d+\.htm$ $1.htm [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, i tried on htaccess tester - http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, however for some reason it doesnt work on my wordpress site. any ideas?

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.+)-\d+\.html$ $1/ [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Did you send the file in text mode on your server ? Or try another browser (cache issue 301, make your test with 302)

Comment: In your comment you write `.html` and `.htm` in your question... You can test both with `RewriteRule ^(.+)-\d+\.html?$ $1.htm [R=301,NC]`